# Setting up and reading an array of .NET structs in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I have a .NET struct containing floats and ints, and I have a method that returns an array of that struct.

How do I initialize a reference to an array of .NET structs in LabVIEW, so that I can read out the floats and ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use the .NET structs method (GetArray)? That would return an array of .NET objects, that you could read in a for loop for instance.
Could you show your code?
If you want to initaite the .NET struct you would need to create a .NET constructor for you object.

Comment: Iterating through it was the answer!